Using Gparted on live Ubuntu to change the size of HoloISO partitions results in FEATURE_C12 errors
I'm currently trying to increase the size of the var partition of a HoloISO installation using a live version of Ubuntu by decreasing the size of the home partition. Tring to do so produces this error:

holo_home: *********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors ***********
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021) /dev/sda4 has unsupported feature(s):
FEATURE_C12 e2fsck: Get a newer version of e2fsck!

Other posts have advised me that actually updating e2fsck is a bad idea, and so I've followed their advice to instead use

tune2fs -O ^orphan_file

This results in a "Invalid filesystem option set: ^orphan_file" error. Looking at the tune2fs documentation I can't even find orphan_file in the -O section, so I'm assuming that has been recently depreciated, but I can't find any resources as to what exactly it did and what its replacement is, if any.
Please let me know if any step in the process was flawed.

What version of Ubuntu is this ?

Your 2nd link says the orphan_file feature was added in version 1.47 You're using an earlier version so it is not "recently deprecated" but does not yet exist in your version.

@SorenA 22.04.4-desktop-amd64
